# How to provide animation when calling another activity in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I have two Activities A and B. I want to have the shrink Animation when 
Activity A calls B and maximize animation when Activity B calls A. I don't need the animation xml files for this.

When we call another Activity in Android it gives its default animation and then it calls shrink animation.

What I want is that the default animation should not occur and the animation that I want should occur.

Can we actually give the animation when calling another Activity?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Since API 16 you can supply an activity options bundle when calling [Context.startActivity(Intent, Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle)) or related methods. It is created via the [ActivityOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html) builder:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
ActivityOptions options = 
   ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
context.startActivity(myIntent, options.toBundle());
```

Don't forget to check out the other methods of the ActivityOptions builder and the [ActivityOptionsCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html) if you are using the Support Library.

---

**API 5+:**

For apps targeting API level 5+ there is the Activities [`overridePendingTransition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)) method. It takes two resource IDs for the incoming and outgoing animations. An id of `0` will disable the animations. Call this immediately after the `startActivity` call.

i.e.:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

---

**API 3+:**

You can prevent the default animation (Slide in from the right) with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` flag in your intent.

i.e.:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

then in your Activity you simply have to specify your own animation.

This also works for the 1.5 API (Level 3).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "specify your own animation"? How do you do this? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question. Probably in start animation in onResume and onPause.

Comment: is there a way to use Animator instead?

Comment: You can also use the same after calling finish()!

Comment: Isn't `R.anim.fade_in` still an xml file animation we suppose to have in `res\anim`  ?

Answer (score 78):

You must use OverridePendingTransition method to achieve it, which is in the [Activity class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Sample Animations in the apidemos example's res/anim folder. Check it. More than check the demo in [ApiDemos/App/Activity/animation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Animation.html).

Example:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    // TODO LC: preliminary support for views transitions
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_right, R.anim.out_to_left);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The method overridePendingTransition is supported from API level 5 and I want the application to be supported from Android 1.5. Is there any other way of providing Animation from one Activity to other.

Comment: awesome! this is a lot of fun to play with

Comment: @sunil i have same quetion like yours.could you solve the problem?animation with api level 3 or 4 ( not 5 )

Comment: keeping animation code in onResume() will cause the animation to play when the user goes outside the app and comes back. Not ideal in many apps.

Comment: I needed to add `super.onResume();`, was getting: *"android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.abc.MyActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()"*

Answer (score 3):

Jelly Bean adds support for this with the [ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html#makeCustomAnimation%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) method. Of course, since it's only on Jelly Bean, it's pretty much worthless for practical purposes.

Comment: It's not worthless anymore :)

Comment: Use `ActivityOptionsCompat` if you target pre-JellyBean.