# Calling setContentView() multiple times

Tags: android

Is there a way to call `setContentView(id)` multiple times with different `id` during one Activity to render different views or do I absolutely have to start a new Activity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per Austyn's comment, I did manage to locate some guidance on how to use ViewFlipper to accomplish this in another post (see the checkmarked top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666966/how-can-i-make-a-dynamic-flipping-screenlike-that-of-iphone-in-android).)

If you don't want to use ViewFlipper, I found a nice example of how to switch between layouts in the same view [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130413065406/http://www.ceveni.com/2009/07/switching-between-layouts-in-android.html):

XML:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Learn-Android.com"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Code:

```
private void SwitchLayout2() {
RelativeLayout Layout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
RelativeLayout Layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);

// Enable Layout 2 and Disable Layout 1
Layout1 .setVisibility(View.GONE);
Layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void SwitchLayout1() {
RelativeLayout Layout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
RelativeLayout Layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);

// Enable Layout 1 & Disable Layout2
Layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: You should really be using a `ViewFlipper` to do this and not just changing the visibility on each `View`

Comment: @AustynMahoney, it'd be great to know the reason why it's best practice to use a ViewFlipper instead of glenviewjeff's described method.

Comment: Why would you want to reinvent the wheel when Android already provides a very simple way to accomplish this exact thing? What happens when you want to expand this to 3 layouts, or maybe 18? If you used `ViewFlipper` it's dead simple, if you didn't well good luck maintaining that code base.

Comment: Given link of example is in underconstruction.

Comment: Fixed with archive.org @PratikButani

Comment: This will cause unnecessarily memory load. Every layout will be created and kept in the memory, when you make them visible/invisible they are just shown on hidden. So say, if you have 5 layouts, you are unnecessarily loading a lot of UI component, which is why this is a bad design.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't call it multiple times easily. You either need to entirely remove all views and then inflate the new layout, or use a `ViewFlipper` (or `FrameLayout`) to switch between different views.

On a side note, this question has been asked before, although I couldn't immediately find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this from your activity:

```
getWindow().addContentView(View, ViewGroup.LayoutParams);
```

The two content view's will be one on top of the other. But, there's no straight forward way to remove a certain view added this way.

Also note that calling `setContentView` after the last call, will remove all previous added content views.