# Changing the content view dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, tablelayout

I am new to android and am trying to figure out how to change the `contentView` at will.

Right now, I have a `TableLayout` in the content view and it was set using the `setContentView(TableLayout)` method.

However, if I wanted to change this **contentview** within the same activity, how would I invoke this? Would I simply invoke the same method like: `setContentView(TableLayout2)` or would I need to clear the screen first?

What is the procedure for staying within the same activity and changing the content on the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: `setContentView(yourLayout);` is set contentView which you have set at last. no need to clear.

Answer (score 4):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4018810/1318946) might help.

> No, you can't call it multiple times
>   easily. You either need to entirely
>   remove all views and then inflate the
>   new layout, or use a ViewFlipper (or
>   FrameLayout) to switch between
>   different views.

Comment: How would I be able to remove all the views (dynamically of course)? Just so I clarify my intentions I'm trying to change the view of the activity when someone fires an event (in this case a click event).

Comment: you can call removeAllViews() on any ViewGroup (including TableLayout) and then add new views to it. In my experience this gets fairly slow if you try to do it too often though.

Comment: if I do this can I re-use (for lack of better terminology) the setContentView(tableLayout)? i.e.

Comment: you would be reusing the original tableLayout, adding new rows.

Comment: thanks. is it possible to call setContentView then removeAllViews then call setContentView again?

Comment: I don't think so, given the answer I linked to.