# using durandaljs hottowel - I want to change the view dynamically but activate does not let me do it

Tags: durandal, hottowel

I am using Durandal, hottowel. Want to change the view dynamically, hide some div depending upon a cookie value. However, if I write the code in "activate" as such

```
  $("#box1").hide();
  $("#box2").show();
```

both the boxes are shown, hide does not work. But if I wire the same code to a click event then everything works. Is "activate" is not the right place to do such a thing? What's the best way to do such a thing.

```
My view is simply as follows:
<section>
     <div id="box1">
            box1
    </div>
        <div id="box2">
               box2
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: When the activate is fired, the view is still not added to the dom. so $('#box1') and $('#box2') do not exist at that point. You should work with observables to show and hide various regions on your UI instead of working with jQuery like that. Another approach would be to put your hide/show logic inside a document.ready function and it would work fine.

Answer (score 4):

A better approach is to use the knockout bindings that ship with durandal to do this declaratively in the view.

```
<section>
    <div data-bind="visible: box1Visible">
        box1
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: box2Visible">
        box2
    </div>
</section>
```

VM:

```
return {
    activate: activate,
    box1Visible: ko.observable(false),
    box2Visible: ko.observable(true)
}
```

Then all you have to do to show or hide the boxes is set the values of those observables from the view model. The view model then doesn't need to be aware of the structure or the names of elements in the view.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the answer by using ViewAttached in my model. This method is called after view  is bound. read more about it here http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206102/changing-the-content-view-dynamically)