# How to change content view from a GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm working on a small game and I'm having problems changing my Activity's content view when a GLSurfaceView is set, let me describe how the app works:

The app has only one Activity, it starts with a static view: `setContentView(R.layout.main);`, when the user sends a certain input using menus a `GLSurfaceView` is instantiated and set via `setContentView(gameSession);` (where gameSession is the class extending GLSurfaceView). The GLSurfaceView class then sets the Renderer on which the real application logic runs.

What happens now is that the game logic (ran inside the `Renderer`) is the one responsible for knowing when the game is over and the view should change back to `R.layout.main`, the Renderer then calls a `synchronized` method on the GLSurfaceView, which notifies the Activity to be changed (again with `setContentView(R.layout.main);`).

And here comes the problem, as soon as `setContentView(R.layout.main);` is called everything hangs, the GLSurfaceView is still there (just not getting updated anymore). I fear that I'm experiencing a deadlock, with the `Activity` waiting for the `Renderer` to be done before removing it.

I've been thinking on a few solutions but all of them bring other issues:

1. Having the `GLSurfaceView` or the `Activity` see if the game is over by polling a flag on the Renderer, but there is no loop on those classes, (and the `onDraw` on the `GLSurfaceView` is never called)
2. Using the `queueEvent()` method, but the `Renderer` class doesn't have it (and using `GLSurfaceView.queueEvent()` doesn't work because the `Runnable` remains of the Renderer thread)
3. Implementing some kind of message thread only to check for game end, but that sounds like a waste of resources.

---

Has any one of you experienced a similar issue? What's the best way to change your `Activity`'s content view from a `GLSurfaceView` to something else if the logic for when to swap is on the `Renderer`?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using different activities and switching between them using intents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `setContentView()` [multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018772/calling-setcontentview-multiple-times/4018810#4018810).

You could instead use multiple activities, calling `finish()` on your game activity when you're done with it to return to the static view Activity.

Comment: Thanks, calling finish() just stops everything and I don't have to care at all about multi-threading, it also looks smoother on transition ;)

Comment: cool! Consider marking accepting answers using the green checkmark. It benefits both you and the answerer and encourages people to answer your questions in the future.