# Calling setcontentview multiple times?

Tags: android

Can i call setcontentview multiple times if my layout is same but the resource changes.for instance if images get exchanged in 2 imageview widgets??(this is infact all that is happening in my app)

Answer (score 2):

You can switch the setContentView several times. However, I have learned in practice, that UI elements don't cross over. In other words each time you set the view, you have to re-findViewById for your UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for ViewFlipper. Follow this link,it may help you.

[Calling setContentView() multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018772/calling-setcontentview-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

You can "refresh" the ImageViews by calling

[myImageView.invalidate();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)

This will make the view be redrawn. If you're using an AdapterView (such as a ListView) call

[myListView.notifyDataSetChanged();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)