# inheritance of custom activities with overloading setContentView, setListAdapter and etc

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity, overloading

Dear Fellow Developers

Need your advice about the architecture design, specifically about the **inheritance of custom activities**.
In my case, there is a necessity to create a music application with the exactly same functionally like the original one but with a different UI and behavior.

Please, hit me whether the approach described below is right or not. I would appreciate your suggestions how to **use maximally functionalities of already implemented activities**.

I think to inherit my track browser, playlist browser, media playback and etc. activities from the standard ones of the original music player. Then I would need to replace the layout and intercept with appropriate handling some events.

**Challenge 1:**
*setContentView* sets already the layout inside *onCreate* of an original activity. I need to call *super.onCreate* in my *onCreate* and then call *setContentView* again. I’ve investigated that it’s possible to [call *setContentView* several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052484/calling-setcontentview-multiple-times) but it’s necessary to instantiate all UI elements each time again. I think that they may be performance and compatibility problems.
**My suggestion 1:**
overload *setContentView* and detect if the instance of the appropriate layout is passed. In case it’s we inflate the activity.

**Challenge 2:**
almost all members are private in original activities but I would need to replace the adapter and may be some broadcast receivers loaded in the original activities.
**My suggestion 2:**
again I can overload *setListAdapter*, *registerReceivers* and etc. and check what kind of instances they try to load. If the instances are not ones of my classes I would skip loading them otherwise I would load it.

I’m searching a root conception of a big project so I would like to be sure if my thinking is right in advance.
Please, point whether I’m not violating conceptions of Android applications design.

Comment: what language you are talking about??

Comment: java in android. Sorry, my first post :)

Comment: and there is such a pretty `android` tag ^^
retaged, so the right people will see this question

Comment: thnx :) Hope it will help to get more responses...