# ImageButton not doing anything on click - android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Im doing the front-end of my new app on android, and I came across with a problem.
On my first Activity my button works fine and take the user to the second Activity, now the problem appear.
When I click on another button to take me to a third Activity nothing happens.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton saldoButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.saldoButton);

    saldoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_saldo);

        }
    });
}
```

now follow my xml of this button:

```
            <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/saldoButton"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/test02" />
```

Anyone has a clue what is happening?

Comment: You need to call 'findViewById' once again to regain access to your ImageView
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052484/calling-setcontentview-multiple-times

Comment: Just be sure only calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_saldo);` doesn't mean you are starting new activity, it is the same activity with only layout will be changed. And to interact with new layout view you have to define views again using `findViewById()`.

Comment: @TyMarc where I need to call it again ?

Comment: @user370305 Im using `setContentView` to go to my third Activity, its another layout. I still doesnt get what I need to do for this button starting working.

Comment: @CássioBruzasco You should read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: @ci_ I read this doc and I made this `android:onClick="saldo"` on my ImageButton on xml and `public void saldo(View v) {

                ImageButton saldoButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.saldoButton);

        saldoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(FirstPage.this,saldo.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }` and my app crashs.

Comment: Add the logcat output when you click on your button, it will help us to help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start third activity

```
saldoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent i= new Intent(currentActivity.this,thirdActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Still not working. I already tried this, but I gave another try and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `android:clickable="true"` on your XML.

```
        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/saldoButton"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/test02" />
```

And then on your **class activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton saldoButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.saldoButton);

    saldoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("This Class", "I am a working button!");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewClass.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

it should work now. If it doesn't, please tell me. Good luck!

Comment: hm, that is weird. Are you getting any errors? How exactly are you testing whether it is working or not?

Comment: try to start the new activity like this:

_Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewClass.class);
context.startActivity(intent);_

Comment: Im clicking on it, and the buttons gets with a light blue around, meaning that Its been clicked, and nothing is happening

Comment: Alright. Add a _Log.d("Class Name", "I am a working button!");_ inside the onClick, just to know whether the problem is on the button or not. I'm pretty sure the issue is when calling the new activity, tho.

Comment: I've edited the answer, please try it out and tell me if it works. :)

Comment: great! It means the ImageButton is not working. Try adding _android:onClick="scrollToTop"_ to the XML. Could you send me the project or is it too big/private?

Comment: Sure, its a college project. Its just front-end devel, give me an email or something

Comment: diego.boarutto.fortes@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inflating a new layout, you need to call once again `findViewById` to regain access to your ImageView since the ID of your button in one layout layout is not the same in another layout.

```
saldoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saldo);
        saldoButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.saldoButton);
    }
});
```

That being said, you should create another activity or another fragment instead of inflating another layout.

Answer (score 0):

add android:clickable="true" in ImageButton XML.

Define and Initialization AudioManger.

```
var audioManager:AudioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) 
as AudioManager
```

after that.

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
        audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN,1f);
    })
```