# Using buttons on android - newbie

Tags: java, android, button

I am a newbie to android development, trying to get buttons working. every time i use this code below, the error message "unfortunately the app has stopped". but when i remove the code the app runs but obviously the buttons do nothing.  here is the code ive tried

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ExerciseButton);
    button1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.exercises);

}

});
}
}
```

anybody able to help me out there? thanks

Comment: by On click, are you trying to load another xml? Or migrate to another activity?

Comment: Post your logcat. Are you getting NPE or what?

Comment: Unfortunately, the app has stopped is not enough to identify the problem you need to post exception details displayed in Android Monitor > logcat (in android studio)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to load another View in the current activity. Navigate to a new ExercisesActivity.
Use:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ExercisesActivity.this, WcActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call setContentView anymore after the view has loaded (which it obviously has to receive button clicks). Use a different approach, like showing and hiding views or using a ViewFlipper (see [Calling setContentView() multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018772/calling-setcontentview-multiple-times)), using fragments (see [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)) or starting a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your code, I see a couple of things:

I am usually familiar to using the onClickListener of the Button class if I want to use it for a button. Makes sense, doesn't it?

```
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do stuff here
}
```

Second thing:

Start a new Activity (if that is what you want) by using an ***Intent***:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, exercises.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You CAN absolutaly call setContentView  on any event, even after the view has loaded
I tried your code in a demo project and it is working fine. So, i think the error will be some where in your layout.(Let me know more if you need more help on this)