# Only able to navigate to the extra layout for the first click

Tags: java, android

The following code is trivial but simulates the problem.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGoToExtra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="266dp"
        android:text="Go To Extra"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**layout_extra.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBackToMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="186dp"
        android:text="Back To Main"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btnGoToExtra)
                .setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    setContentView(R.layout.layout_extra);
                    findViewById(R.id.btnBackToMain)
                            .setOnClickListener(vv -> {
                                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                            });
                });
    }
}
```

## Question

I can navigate to the `layout_extra` from `activity_main` and return to `activity_main`. Unfortunately, after this round trip, I can no longer be able to navigate to `layout_extra` anymore.

What causes this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Did I abuse `setContentView` for page navigation here? I am new to Android programming to be honest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation will follow in chat but that is not how it is supposed to be done, For views to change, You have other options like using Fragments or using new activity entirely, I would also like to suggest moving to kotlin.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    View mainView;
    View extraView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        extraView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_extra, null);
        setContentView(mainView);

        mainView.findViewById(R.id.btnGoToExtra)
                .setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    setContentView(extraView);
                });
        extraView.findViewById(R.id.btnBackToMain)
                .setOnClickListener(vv -> {
                    setContentView(mainView);
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the snippet above, here's how everything went

The line

```
findViewById(R.id.btnGoToExtra)
               .setOnClickListener
```

Registers Button with id **btnGoToExtra** for click events and when that happens you have the nested

```
findViewById(R.id.btnBackToMain)
                            .setOnClickListener
```

Which registers the element with id **backToMain** for click events and that's all

Calling **setContentView()** multiple times is not recommended. The normal way to switch between layouts in the same activity is to use a ViewFlipper or FrameLayout

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938835/13522090)

You then have:

**XML**

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Learn-Android.com"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**code**

```
private void SwitchLayout2() {
RelativeLayout Layout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
RelativeLayout Layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);

// Enable Layout 2 and Disable Layout 1
Layout1 .setVisibility(View.GONE);
Layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void SwitchLayout1() {
RelativeLayout Layout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
RelativeLayout Layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);

// Enable Layout 1 & Disable Layout2
Layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Trying to digest what you explained. :-)