# Android Studio: Can I use one java class for multiple layouts?

Tags: android-studio, layout

I'm a beginner in Android Studio and am trying to figure out how to edit different layouts(.xml files) with one java class(.java). I am trying to get the id of an ImageView on another layout, but the findViewById of the ImageView returned null. What do I need to do? Also, I have two layout files because I am using a popupWindow. So, I need to access the ImageView of the popupWindow.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "trying to edit different layouts with one java class"? Are you trying to include multiple layouts in one activity?

Comment: It can be achieved by using a flag to determine the layout file to load in your setContentView method but I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: @TechnoBlahble Yes, multiple layouts in one activity. I'm using a popupWindow to display the second layout.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943862/calling-multiple-layouts-in-one-activity-on-2-different-call-backs

Comment: If you want to use multiple layouts you might want to use <include> tag in your layout and reference that layout in your activity. You can read more about it at -http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: @TechnoBlahble The <include> tag just sandwiches the two layouts together, because I am using a popupWindow I don't want that window to already be up. I just need a way to access the ImageView of the popup but it returns null

Comment: Did you try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android

Comment: @TechnoBlahble Yep, tried an alert already. Functionality is too limited.

Comment: @Hudson Describe how `AlertDialog` is limited. You can inflate a custom layout into it.

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't call an AlertDialog outside of the onCreate, which is essential to what I'm doing.

Comment: @Hudson Sure you can... make a `dialog` field variable. Use `AlertDialog.Builder` in `onCreate` to build the dialog. Call `dialog.show()` and `dialog.hide()` and `dialog.findViewById()` wherever you need to.

Comment: @cricket_007 What is a dialog field variable? Maybe an example would help

Comment: @Hudson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable

Comment: @karaokyo like this? public void dialog{//Enter further dialogbuilder code here}

Comment: @cricket_007 Like this? public void dialog{//Enter further dialogbuilder code here}

Comment: @Hudson Nope. I'm fairly confident that this question could be answered in 30 seconds if you had posted an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @karaokyo It would be nice to show me what a dialog field variable is.

Comment: Java. Fields. Make one for the dialog. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are just using `Activity`'s `findViewById`, which would search the activity's layout for your `ImageView`. You would need to call `findViewById` on your inflated popup view:

```
View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

//Get your image view from the inflated popup
ImageView image = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!