# Change Layout when Thread finish

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, view

I want to change the layout when a thread ends, but I don't understand the bug; for example:

**res/layout:**

-mainView.xml

-threadView.xml

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void firstThread() {

    setContentView(R.layout.threadView);        

    firstThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SystemClock.sleep(7000);

            setContentView(R.layout.threadView);        
        }           
    });
    firstThread.start();          
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    firstThread();
}
```

Thanks for all!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: switching screens with new activity or just changing content view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811989/android-switching-screens-with-new-activity-or-just-changing-content-view)

Comment: I guess you got confused with threads and UI, there's only one MainThread/UIThread in Android. and you cannot set views for a BackgroundThread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify UI thread from any other thread. Either you can post a message from your other thread and write a handler in UI thread to change the layout. Try using Asynctask. your life will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

At least you should post the error stack for everyone to see your problem. Assume there is a problem, I guess it is because you cant modify the UI in another thread. Try inside your thread:

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                setContentView(R.layout.threadView); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all!

I resolved the isuue using the next resolution:

http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/using-a-viewswitcher-in-your-android-xml-layouts/

I was trying to change the layout within thread and not through the handler!