# How can get a Layout animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to put some animation in switching between activities in android similar to windows 7. Clicking on something will take us to the new screen with the windows 7 screen flying animation. I tried custom animation but i don't think i am even close to achieve it. Does anybody know some links regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Show a Frame-by-frame animation before switching to the new activity.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319835/animation-before-activity-change) would be helpful to achieve what u need.