# TextView.setVisibility not working before Activity change

Tags: android, textview

I have some code that looks like this:

```
loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading);

public void enterButton(View v) { // This is a button
    loading.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE); // For some reason this does not happen...
    MyApp.initialize(); // ... before this is completed
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}
```

loading is a TextView that simply says, "Loading...". MyApp.initialize() is a computationally heavy method that sets up AnotherActivity. It take several seconds to run, which is why I want the "Loading..." message to appear.

The problem is that most of the time loading.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE) doesn't seem to do anything. I never see the text. On rare occasions I see "Loading..." flash briefly right before the Activity changes. Something tells me that Android is putting loading.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE) on a stack or something and then not getting around to doing it until after MyApp.initialize() is completed, which is obviously too late. I would like for "Loading..." to appear before MyApp.initialize() starts.

[Animation BEFORE activity change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319835/animation-before-activity-change) looks like it's close, but .setAnimationListener doesn't work for a TextView. Is there something similar for a TextView? I took a crack with this but the application hung:

```
loading.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE); 
loading.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {               
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        MyApp.initialize();
        Intent i = new Intent(MyApp.getInstance(), AnotherActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try using a Async task to show the text and do your `MyApp.initialize()` in `doInBackground` and call the intent in `onPostExecute`, which is something like

```
private ProcessDataAsync processDataAsync;

    public class ProcessDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            MyApp.initialize();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Intent i = new Intent(context, AnotherActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
```

Then call the asynctask in your onClickListener as

```
    processDataAsync = new ProcessDataAsync();
    processDataAsync.execute((Void[]) null);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sweet. AsyncTask<> is exactly what I need. And thank you for the code! I'm not very familiar with threads, so they're a bit confusing right now. I'm going to have to read up on that. This might be off-topic for this question, but I'm also going to have to figure out how to "disable" the current Activity so that the user can't mash the button several times and fire off a bunch of MyApp.initialize() threads. I suppose that's probably not too hard if I do it in onPreExecute(). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure (because it's not obvious looking at your code), but seems like you're doing everything in one thread. Changing visibility calls invalidate method, which will cause the view to be redrawn in the NEXT DRAW CALL. The TextView will be visible only after next draw call, which may not happen due to activity change.

You should set visibility as usual and start a new thread with initialization and intent call. Maybe you should also call invalidate manually. This will do the trick. Your app will initialize in background and the drawing thread will show the TextView.

Comment: Yep, this is it. Everything is in one thread, so I need to spin off a 2nd. "The TextView will be visible only after next draw call, which may not happen due to activity change." <-- This is probably the case. It's odd, however, since all of the calculations in MyApp.initialize() take several seconds, that the next draw call doesn't occur sooner.

Answer (score 1):

You should use thread, or asynctask for the init work.

```
loading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading);
Handler h = new Handler();
public void enterButton(View v) { // This is a button
    loading.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyApp.initialize();
            h.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but my guess is that it won't make much of a difference. TextView extends View and VISIBLE is an inherited constant: <http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#inhconstants>