# Transition of Activity A to Activity B. Can this transition be like a rotation, instead of a regular Android activity show?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

In the Apk Demos for HoneyComb under Views/Animation/3D Transition I see that when we click the image list, they show with an animation of turning the ImageView.

Is this possible for transitioninng between activities?

Ex: 
Opned app A.
Click on a list item, this click opens a new activity.(Here I want the new activity that is displayed to look like as if it was hiding in the back)

Activity B is rotated into the front of the screen from Activity A.

Thanks,
Sana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can change the animation when your activity is started, I'm not sure but you could probably get a 3D effect with it. See [Applying Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) - you need to change the `android:windowAnimationStyle` of your theme.

Your themes.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="MyApplicationTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ActivityAnimation</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Your styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="ActivityAnimation">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_open_enter</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/activity_open_exit</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_close_enter</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/activity_close_exit</item>
    <item name="android:taskOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/task_open_enter</item>
    <item name="android:taskOpenExitAnimation">@anim/task_open_exit</item>
    <item name="android:taskCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/task_close_enter</item>
    <item name="android:taskCloseExitAnimation">@anim/task_close_exit</item>
    <item name="android:taskToFrontEnterAnimation">@anim/task_open_enter</item>
    <item name="android:taskToFrontExitAnimation">@anim/task_open_exit</item>
    <item name="android:taskToBackEnterAnimation">@anim/task_close_enter</item>
    <item name="android:taskToBackExitAnimation">@anim/task_close_exit</item>
    <item name="android:wallpaperOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_open_enter</item>
    <item name="android:wallpaperOpenExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_open_exit</item>
    <item name="android:wallpaperCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_close_enter</item>
    <item name="android:wallpaperCloseExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_close_exit</item>
    <item name="android:wallpaperIntraOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_open_enter</item>
    <item name="android:wallpaperIntraOpenExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_open_exit</item>
    <item name="android:wallpaperIntraCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_close_enter</item>
    <item name="android:wallpaperIntraCloseExitAnimation">@anim/wallpaper_intra_close_exit</item>
</style> 

</resources>
```

Then set `android:theme="@style/MyApplicationTheme` in the `<application>` (applies to all activities) or `<activity>` tag (applies the theme to just that activity, and overrides the application theme if set) in your Android manifest.

Comment: it just applies the theme, but it doesn't change the transitions. :(

Comment: and I defined for each @anim in my anims folder?

Comment: Yes, make animations called `activity_open_enter.xml`, `activity_open_exit.xml` in your anims folder. You can change the names of course, just remember to change the ones in your styles file to match.

Comment: android:theme="@style/MyTheme and android:windowAnimationStyle="@style/ActivityAnimation". What is the difference between the two?

Comment: the transformation happens only on the x and y axis. I am looking for animation on the z-axis as well.

Comment: Added more information in the post on how to apply the theme and style. But yes you probably only can use the animation on the X and Y axis. You could still use a skewing animation to give the effect of spinning.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question...  see question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651360/how-to-provide-animation-when-calling-another-activity-in-android).

Or, a direct link to the android example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Animation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I do not think Android provides ways to implement 3D transitions between activities.

Comment: I think you may be right, I didn't find any existing UIs to do this.