# android activity transaction style?

Tags: android, android-layout

i need to know whether transaction style is possible or not in android , for example if i launch the main activity i need to go or switch over to second activity ,i need some animation like popup , pop for left..etc , for next activity view. whether it is possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Intend` to go another activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, TagetActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
```

Further to understand about intend:

> http://www.castlerockresearch.in/dev/2010/08/understanding-intents-and-intent-filters-in-android/

For Pop up animation see this link:

> http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/04/animated-customized-popup-transparent.html

Comment: Thanks.But i don`t need popup animation , i need to start normal activity with animation.

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
      FromActivity.this.startActivity(i);
      overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);` fadein and fadeout are animations u created in anim of Resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for switching between 2 activities.
For the animation part please look at this [How to provide animation when calling another activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651360/how-to-provide-animation-when-calling-another-activity-in-android)

This could also be useful:

- anddev.org/animation_on_new_intent-t1207.html

BR,
mybecks