# Effect in Android during changing the Activity

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-widget

I want to set the Animation during calling the Activity from one to another activity.
I know its possible threw the Animation xml file. But I want to set the Animation as like that. . .
While the activity is called, current screen goes current position to the left and the new activity screen comes from left to the current screen. . .
 for that how to set XML file. . . 
Thanks in Advance. . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity transition in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Try this [How to provide animation when calling another activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651360/how-to-provide-animation-when-calling-another-activity-in-android/3139403#3139403) or this [Activity transition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android/3389558#3389558)

Comment: Nice to hear from you that. . I have done animation from here : http://www.41post.com/3368/programming/android-changing-the-animation-between-activities

Comment: Now, i want to set the such effect.. While i call the new Activity, the present window goes to the left and the new wondow comes from the right to the current position. .