# Android listview row pressed animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, selector, transition

In my app, I have a custom listview. User can press a row of the listview and then another activity(detail of row)  becomes visible. My question is, After user click, I want to show an click animation to the button before detailed activity becomes visible (note this state is not 'pressed state', is 'after pressed'). At first, I thought I could make this by selectors. But as far as I know, selectors can animate at pressed, focused states. After hands-off, click animaton becomes invisible. But I need a click animation through the transition.

How can I do this ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This might be very relevant:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651360/how-to-provide-animation-when-calling-another-activity-in-android

Comment: I don't need activity transition animation, I need button click animation!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an easier way to do this, but this is what I would do. For your ListView, set it an `onItemClickListener` like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        view.startAnimation(animation);
        // do everything else when the user clicks on an item
}
```

And for the object `animation`, design it in XML, and turn it into an `Animation` object like this:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.animation);
```