# How to start an Activity with an animation set entirely programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am trying to animate the way a new Activity appears. Default is to slide in. I have an animation set that I would like to somehow append to the Intent or the Activity so that it will start when I call startActivity.

The catch is that I need to do this completely programmatically. I cannot declare any XML resources for animations, etc. How would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651360/how-to-provide-animation-when-calling-another-activity-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code snippet

```
startActivity(intent);

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

slide_in_right

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

slide_out_left

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-50%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

You can tiker with the codes to get your desire effect.

Comment: He said, NO XML declaration. This doesn't point the problem

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` has a method called [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) that you can use to pass in new animations. So you would just call this in the `onCreate` of your `Activity`.

Comment: He said `completely programmatically`.

Comment: This is completely programmatically.  I didn't say anything about modifying resource files.

Comment: What would I specify the animations? They need integer ids that refer to some resource either generated from my XML file (which is not what I want to do) or already provided by Google (which doesn't exist to my knowledge)...

Comment: @CaseyB: As mentioned, "I cannot declare any XML resources for animations". And overridePendingTransition() takes two xml resources params.

Comment: There are animations built into the OS.  You can use those.  You needn't declare your own.