# Fade in animation for Activity

Tags: android, animation

I am new to Android. When I open a new activity, I need to create an fade in animation for the opening activity. eg: Currently I am in activity "A", now I want to open another activity "B" on a button click. Now I could open an activity without any animation. But I would like to give a Fade In animation. Now, following code is used to open an activity.

```
Intent profileActivity = new Intent(Login.this, Profile.class);
startActivityForResult(profileActivity, 0);
```

Here "profileActivity" should open with a Fade In animation. What could I make in the above code to make an animation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651360/how-to-provide-animation-when-calling-another-activity-in-android, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android

Answer (score 7):

Just add this line to your calling intent :

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

it will look like that :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

Then create an "anim" folder under your "res" folder and add these 2 xml files

slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

As you can see I'm just doing a translation animation if you want to add a fading effect just add

```
android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I think "overridePendingTransition" is using in latest API. Am I right?

Comment: in my app I'm using android api version 2.2 which is fair I think.

Comment: ok moujib, Thank you. I will let you know the comments after trying out this. once again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

This is the code of fade animation
R.anim.fade

```
 <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
           android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Answer (score 2):

thank for @moujib answer, I've never known that before. What I did is to manually apply the animation as soon as the second activity is started. Using overridePendingTransition() is a lot cleaner (it's available in api 5 or up). Aside to @moujib answer, you don't have to define the fade in animation by yourself as Android already had it defined. Take a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim.html

Comment: Ah. That developer link was helpful. Thanks. I was almost considering checking that API SDK samples' project. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Android Animation](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html)

U can put your welcome page with progress bar the above link will help you how to add animation in a activity

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line of code for smooth transition from one activity to other:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, DestinationActivity::class.java),ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(this,R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out).toBundle())
```