# How to make animation when switching between activities programmatically

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I don't want to make the animation using the xml resources. how to make is usign the code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create activity transition animation programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830038/how-to-create-activity-transition-animation-programmatically)

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651360/how-to-provide-animation-when-calling-another-activity-in-android