# Activity inside activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity with `ListView` and 2nd activity which have `ViewPager`. Now I want in one activity if status true then go to 2nd activity `

```
 Intent n = new Intent(one, two);

 startActivity(n);`
```

But here problem is it giving opening animation is any i can do within that 1st activity 
 any way i can avoid that animation and it look like it is same activity

or i have to redo full code and this inside 2 fragments ? so have one fragment activity and then but one activity code inside fragment and two activity inside fragment which will have view pager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide animation when calling another activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651360/how-to-provide-animation-when-calling-another-activity-in-android)

Comment: @bob : You should use 'Fragments'..!!

Comment: view pager inside fragment will work /?

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing you, your are trying to call activity B from activity A, based on a result, which is an item picked from list item, however you wanna avoid any sort of screen transitions (animations) when moving from one another.

I may be wrong but my google search didn`t revealed any way to avoid transition between activities.What your could actually do is to refactor your code using fragments and sort them out within the parent activity view group in a way that fragment B maximizes itself or pops up over fragment A pausing it.

Brs.,