# How to show Animated activity in onPreExecute?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on an activity which uses async task. So I have created an animated activity which I want to show in onPreExecute of this async task and I don't know how to do it.

So is there any way to solve my query?

Comment: put your code what you have tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651360/how-to-provide-animation-when-calling-another-activity-in-android

Comment: I am only using progress dialog.

Comment: As in our splash screen, we can change it in manifest by changing DEFAULT to  LAUNCHER. Can we do something like this on other activities?

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate call some like below

```
mdialog=new Dialog(this);
new LongOperation().execute("");
```

Then override onPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {
   mdialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I have to use Animated activity in onPreExecute.

Comment: OnPostExecute runs on UI thread. It is a built in mechanism from AsyncTask to realize a background operation (doInBackground) for example network request and Update UI onPostExecute.
onPreExecute runs on UIThread too. It is used to show progress bar for example.
Please refer to AsyncTask Doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
You will never use runOnUiThread onPre or onPostExecute!!!